# Has there been systematic studies of how historical contexts and social factors influenced various philosophers?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, history, philosophy-of-history

While I learn a lot from philosophers, I can't help but think that their minds (just like mine) are somewhat tied to the exact times they were born into. The historical context and social factors influenced what they think about, how they think, and also the conclusions they are likely to arrive at.

Is there any systematic studies of this?

Comment: See [Sociology of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology_of_knowledge), "*the study of the relationship between human thought and the social context within which it arises, and of the effects that prevailing ideas have on societies*", and [Sociology of philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology_of_philosophy) more specifically. [Collins's The Sociology of Philosophies](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~cjscopy/reviews/socofphil.html) goes into specific historical thinkers in much detail.

Comment: Oh yes, there are many, but as noted sociology of philosophy would put you on the track. And there are, of course, historical biographies of most well-known philosophers. I will mention just one of my own favorites "Preface to Plato" by Eric Havelock, which examines the origins of Plato's work in the context of the transition from on oral Homeric culture to a culture of writing and general literacy,  "Philosophy in the Flesh" by Lackoff tries to render a history of philosophy via cognitive science.

Comment: Well, the best answer to your question is to study History.  When studying History, you will be able to gain a broader understanding of the time and place that Philosophers lived in and how it is very likely that they were greatly influenced by their national surroundings.  Socrates, for example, was a native Athenian, who hated Democracy, yet, lived during the height of Athenian Democracy.  Aristotle, who was not a native Athenian, though lived in Athens for much of his adult life, was more accepting and tolerant of a quasi Representative Democracy-(or "Polity").  While these are only........

Comment: fractional examples, they do underscore the significance of how national surroundings can impact-(either positively or negatively), a Philosopher's mindset and narrative.